Word break not working properly in exported document from html template
I am trying to export a word document from html. A lot of items are inside a table. When there is a large text without space, the td content takes a lot of space and the title of the table row shrinks so I used word-break: break-all property for word break but it is also breaking a small word which I do not want.
<html>
<head>
    <!-- styles and links imports -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="WordSection1">
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: -4.5pt;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="678">
            <tbody>
                <!-- other table rows -->
                <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
                    <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 148.5pt;" width="198">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"><strong>Project Description</strong></span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 5in; " width="480">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt; width: 100%; word-break: break-all;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;">
                                Redevelopment will include updating mechanical, electrical, and plumbing systems throughout the ground-floor commercial space and office space. Updates include, but are not limited to new cooling towers,
                                water boilers, hydronic system pumps, and piping.
                                asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                            </span>
                            <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"></span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- other table rows -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>


The "word-break:break-all" property breaks the long word but it also breaks a word like "Updates", "hydration" as seen in the picture. I do not want to break those words. I tried word-break: break-word property which seems to work in normal css but not in the exported document from html. Am i missing something?

Can you share with us (with the code) how are you exporting the doc, because the word-break: break-word should have done it too in the exported document.

It seems that you want to break long words but not small words. I don't think this can be achieved by CSS. You could add a small JavaScript function that breaks only long words before exporting your document:


// Let's say you want to break all words greater than 10 chars in length in a div with ID "asdf"
// This also assumes that there the div only contains text and not HTML
function breakOnlyLongWords() {
    var div = document.querySelector('#asdf');
    var text = div.textContent;
    var words = text.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(words[i].length > 10)
            words[i] = breakWord(words[i]);
    }
    div.textContent = words.join(' ');
}

// Function that adds hyphens after every 10 chars in a word longer than 10 chars
function breakWord(word) {
    var chars = word.split('');
    var newWord = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        newWord += chars[i];
        if((i+1) % 10 === 0)
            newWord += '-';
    }
    return newWord.replace(/-$/, '');
}
<button onclick="breakOnlyLongWords();">Add hyphens to long words</button>
<div id="asdf">
Redevelopment will include updating mechanical, electrical, and plumbing systems throughout the ground-floor commercial space and office space. Updates include, but are not limited to new cooling towers,
                                water boilers, hydronic system pumps, and piping.
                                asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>




Thank you for you input but we can achieve this with CSS.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxk9aa?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts
Please go through this stakblitz i just updated

Try set overflow-wrap: anywhere;:


<div class="WordSection1">
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: -4.5pt;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="678">
        <tbody>
             <!-- other table rows -->
             <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
                  <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 148.5pt;" width="198">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt;">
                             <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"><strong>Project Description</strong></span>
                        </p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 5in; " width="480">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt; width: 100%; overflow-wrap: anywhere;">
                             <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;">
                                  Redevelopment will include updating mechanical, electrical, and plumbing systems throughout the ground-floor commercial space and office space. Updates include, but are not limited to new cooling towers,
                                  water boilers, hydronic system pumps, and piping.
                                  asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                             </span>
                             <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"></span>
                        </p>
                  </td>
             </tr>
             <!-- other table rows -->
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



Or wrap "long" words in <span style="word-break: break-all;">:


<div class="WordSection1">
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: -4.5pt;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="678">
        <tbody>
             <!-- other table rows -->
             <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
                  <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 148.5pt;" width="198">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt;">
                             <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"><strong>Project Description</strong></span>
                        </p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 5in; " width="480">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt; width: 100%;">
                             <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;">
                                  Redevelopment will include updating mechanical, electrical, and plumbing systems throughout the ground-floor commercial space and office space. Updates include, but are not limited to new cooling towers,
                                  water boilers, hydronic system pumps, and piping.
                                  <span style="word-break: break-all;">asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                             </span>
                             <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"></span>
                        </p>
                  </td>
             </tr>
             <!-- other table rows -->
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




Thanks for your comment, but  word-break: break-all is working fine when I render the html to browser but I want them in exported doc file. When I export the html to word doc file it is not working the same way. –

exported doc file - what do you mean? My second option is also not working?

Instead of overflow-wrap: anywhere; it's better to use overflow-wrap: break-word; maybe. @SaigalAmatya you can use break-word for export doc, hopefully it will work for your issue.

Problem
Setting word-break to break-all will create a situation that word may be broken at any character. In opposite, setting word-break to break-word will create a situation that each line is broken by words. So, situations likeI am writting a lot of words in this sentence to create the effect o f line break. I am writting a lot of words in this sentence to create the effect of line br eak. I am writting a lot o f words in this sentence to create the effect of line break.  will not happen.
Try this code


<body>
    <div class="WordSection1">
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: -4.5pt;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="678">
            <tbody>
                <!-- other table rows -->
                <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
                    <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 148.5pt;" width="198">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"><strong>Project Description</strong></span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; vertical-align: top; width: 5in; " width="480">
                        <p style="margin: 0in 0in 6pt; width: 100%; word-break: break-word;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;">
                                Redevelopment will include updating mechanical, electrical, and plumbing systems throughout the ground-floor commercial space and office space. Updates include, but are not limited to new cooling towers,
                                water boilers, hydronic system pumps, and piping.
                                asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                            </span>
                            <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10.5pt;"></span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- other table rows -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>



Links
W3school word-break CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.php
MDN web docs word-break CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

This should fix the problem you are having:
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word; 

